# struct with template object inside an templated class

Tags: c++, templates, struct, linked-list

I am trying to create a Templated class to hold different objects to lern a bit about selfwritten datastructures and ptrs which are new to me.
I am stuck at this point:

```
template <class T> class Linked_List
{

    struct Node
    {
        T data;
        Node* prev;
        Node* next;
        Node(T d, Node* p, Node* n) : data(d),
        prev(p), next(n) {}
    };

public:
    Linked_List();
    ~Linked_List();

    void push_back(T data);
    void push_front(T data);
    void insertAt(T data, int pos);

    T pop_back();
    T pop_front();

    int size();
    bool empty();

private:
    Node* tail;
    Node* head;
};
```

I get this error: `'Linked_List<T>::Node::data' uses undefined class 'T'`. (using VS2013)

What have i done wrong?

Thanks

---

Update:

```
#include "Linked_List.h"


template<class T> Linked_List<T>::Linked_List()
{
    head = 0;
    tail = 0;
}

template<class T> Linked_List<T>::~Linked_List()
{
    {
        while (head)
        {
            Node* temp(head); //pointer to head
            head = head->next; // go to next
            delete temp; //delete the pointer
        }
    }
}

template <class T>
void Linked_List<T>::push_back(T data)
{
    //create the new Node
    tail = new Node(data, tail, NULL);
    if (tail->prev) //add to tail
        tail->prev->next = tail;
    if (empty()) // if empty its also the head
        head = tail;
}

template <class T>
void Linked_List<T>::push_front(T data)
{
    head = new Node(data, 0, tail);
    if (head->next)
        head->next->prev = head;
    if (empty())
        tail = head;
}

template <class T>
bool Linked_List<T>::empty()
{
    return (!head || !tail);
}

template <class T>
T Linked_List<T>::pop_back()
{
    if (empty())
        throw("Linked_list is empty!");
    //pointer to the element we want to have
    Node* temp(tail);
    //set the tail to prev
    tail = tail->prev;
    //get the data
    T data = temp->data;

    //the prev does not have a next now
    if (tail)
        tail->next = 0;
    else
        head = 0;

    //delete the node which held our data
    delete temp;
    //return the data
    return data;
}

template <class T>
T Linked_List<T>::pop_front()
{
    if (empty())
        throw("Linked_list is empty!");
    //pointer to the element we want to have
    Node* temp(head);
    //set the tail to prev
    head = head->next;
    //get the data
    T data = temp->data;

    //the prev does not have a next now
    if (head)
        head->prev = 0;
    else
        tail = 0;

    //delete the node which held our data
    delete temp;
    //return the data
    return data;
}
```

new stacktrace if i am trying to use it simply like this

```
int main(){
    Linked_List<int> list;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        list.push_back(i);
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
    {
        cout <<  list.pop_back() << endl;
    }
}
```

Error:

```
 Error  1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Linked_List<int>::Linked_List<int>(void)" (??0?$Linked_List@H@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main   C:\Users\...\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Double_Linked_List\Double_Linked_List\main.obj   Double_Linked_List
    Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Linked_List<int>::~Linked_List<int>(void)" (??1?$Linked_List@H@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main  C:\Users\...\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Double_Linked_List\Double_Linked_List\main.obj   Double_Linked_List
    Error   3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Linked_List<int>::push_back(int)" (?push_back@?$Linked_List@H@@QAEXH@Z) referenced in function _main C:\Users\...\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Double_Linked_List\Double_Linked_List\main.obj   Double_Linked_List
    Error   4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall Linked_List<int>::pop_back(void)" (?pop_back@?$Linked_List@H@@QAEHXZ) referenced in function _main    C:\Users\...\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Double_Linked_List\Double_Linked_List\main.obj   Double_Linked_List
    Error   5   1   error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals   C:\Users\...\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Double_Linked_List\Debug\Double_Linked_List.exe  1   Double_Linked_List
```

Comment: The code above has no issues. My crystal ball tells me the unseen code you chose not to include is the implementation, where you likely didn't define the template function(s) correctly. Ex: `template<class T> void Linked_List<T>::push_back(T data){ .. }`. Note the `template <class T>` preceding the method definition. Also, this *all* belongs in the same header file as the class def.

Comment: Where is the code implementing the member methods?

Comment: ill add it. but didnt want to add so much code to it..

Comment: `Linked_List<class T>::Linked_List()` is invalid syntax. Use `template<class T> Linked_List<T>::Linked_List()` (also note that templates can only be defined in headers)

Comment: changed that thanks for the information. Update the post by the stacktrace

Comment: Also, your `Node` constructor, while it may be valid, will likely eventually cause confusion (using the same names for member variables and constructor parameters).

Comment: Your code compiles fine after adding the necessary headers. Please make sure the definitions (function bodies) of the `Linked_List<T>` member functions are `#include`d in every source file where `Linked_List<T>` is used. See [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/495021/420683)

Comment: i still can't compile it (see error). It's like its uploaded here Just the .h the cpp and the "main" where i try to init one of it with int.  Thanks for the further informations about the templates.

Comment: If the file where the member functions of `Linked_List<T>` reside in is a .cpp (i.e. if the code block in your question that starts with `#include "Linked_List.h"` is a .cpp file), you exactly have the problem described in the answer I just linked. Cut&paste all the contents of this file at the end of your header file and remove the .cpp that formerly contained the code.

Comment: This is confusing. If i past/include it into the .h i get compile erors like unrecognizable template declaration/definition and way more. Thanks alof for the help ... i realy stuck with it.

Comment: *"If i past/include it into the .h i get compile erors like unrecognizable template declaration/definition and way more"* Please post which code block in your question is in which file (now) and how (especially in which order) the headers are included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linker is very clear : you are missing definition of those methods. The compiler doesn't complain, since it see the declaration of the Linked_List class, but when dealing with templates, that is not enough.

In order for the template instantiation to be successful, all template definitions need to be visible. Since, you implemented methods of the template class in a cpp file (people usually do it in the header, or impl file), you need to include that file where the template is being instantiated. In your specific example, in the main.cpp :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Linked_List.cpp"   // !!!


int main(){
    Linked_List<int> list;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        list.push_back(i);
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
    {
        std::cout <<  list.pop_back() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

---

Instead of including the implantation file, and have the compiler implicitly instantiate template, you can do it explicitly in the source file. In this case, add this line at the end of Linked_List.cpp :

```
template class Linked_List<int>;
```

but in that case, you will not be able to create objects with different template argument (other than int).

---

The third option is a variation of the first. Include the source file at the end of the header.

Header

```
// header.hpp
#ifndef HEADER_HPP
#define HEADER_HPP

template< typename T >
struct A
{
    void foo();
};

#include "source.impl"

#endif
```

Source

```
// source.impl

#include "header.hpp"

template< typename T >
void A::foo()
{
}
```

Main

```
// main.cpp

#include "header.hpp"

int main()
{
  A<int> a;
  a.foo();
}
```

Comment: I would not recommend to `#include "Linked_List.cpp"` in main.cpp. (Also, in the second part, what does “at the end of std::” mean?) (Also, “other then” → “other than”.) What I would recommend is to read the answers to [the linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file) (thanks to [DyP's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19875142/struct-with-template-object-inside-an-templated-class#comment29627937_19875142)).

Comment: @gx_ As I said : either implement everything in the header, or include source, or explicit instantiate. errors fixed

Comment: @BЈовићeither    Implement everything in the header is good solution

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you've put the definition of the template class and implementation of its methods in two files, just like what you do for normal non-template classes; and you just include the header file which defines your linked list in your main.cpp.

Please refer to this thread for why you cannot do this

[Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)